# Multiple post in One Loop in wordpress

Tags: posts, loop

I’m converting HTML website to wordpress dynamic and  having trouble getting duplicate posts. Code is following kindly please guide me in this regard m new with wordpress and PHP.

```
<div class="container-fluid white-bg">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row pricing-main">

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h5 class="text-center">See what we Offer in Membership</h5>
        </div>
        <?php  $posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'pricing' , 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
while($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-8 top-spacing col-sm-8">
            <p class="prcng-txt"><?php echo get_the_title();?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_the_content();?>.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 top-spacing col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>" class="img-border img-responsive" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 top-spacing col-sm-12 ">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/divider.png" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 top-spacing col-sm-4">
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>" class="img-border img-responsive hidden-xs" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 top-spacing col-sm-8">
            <p class="prcng-txt"><?php echo get_the_title();?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_the_content();?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got `get_the_content()` and `get_the_title()` twice. You should only have one set of these for each post.

Comment: Dear actually two different styles are there In first title and content firstly it will echo text and in next column Picture and the second content and title it will first echo picture and then text therefore m not getting what should i do ..............